# Rails omniauth + Facebook works in development over http, but not in Production over HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I have a Rails 3.1 application which uses omniauth + Facebook for login auth.

```
omniauth (1.1.0)
  hashie (~> 1.2)
  rack
omniauth-facebook (1.2.0)
  omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.0.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0)
  oauth2 (~> 0.5.0)
  omniauth (~> 1.0)
```

When I've set up the Facebook settings to use localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook, it works great. When I deploy the code into production it doesn't work at all. The main differences are that locally, I'm only using HTTP, and in production Nginx is configured to force HTTPS (by redirecting).

```
initializers/devise.rb
config.omniauth :facebook, '1705xxxxxxxxx586', '173b59ba3xxxxxxxxxxxx893e2e697', :scope => 'email,user_birthday'

initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  #provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
  provider :facebook, '1705xxxxxxxxx586', '173b59ba3xxxxxxxxxxxx893e2e697',
        :scope => 'email,user_birthday',
        :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => '/etc/nginx/certs/cacert.pem'}}
end
```

Has anyone run into this problem before? It appears like the key/secret is not being read in production, but that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Is your SSL certificate valid?  What exactly is going wrong? Any errors in the server logs?

Comment: SSL cert is self-signed, but valid.

    (facebook) Request phase initiated.
    (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
    (facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, OAuth2::Error

Comment: Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML, --- this is in the production.log

Comment: I just disabled SSL on the production instance and it is definitely working now - must be related to SSl connection in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

We traced the problem to an "extra" "?" in the nginx rewrite in its config. In case someone else has this trouble at some point in the future, nginx does exactly what you tell it to do. :)